# Port 2003 not open/listen and can't access data on Graphite

Tags: networking, server, graphite

I'm on Ubuntu Server, and I've installed Graphite and shinken. First I'm trying to get working Graphite (desperatly) but without success.

I've make a netstat to see if my port is open :

```
netstat -tuplen
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7767            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       544010      1816/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7768            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       542859      1194/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      107        9068        931/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7769            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543251      1432/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7771            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543079      1317/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7772            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543634      1579/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7773            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543810      1694/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44255         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543623      1582/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43007         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       542845      1201/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38856         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543911      1793/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57546         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543808      1695/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46282         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543238      1439/python
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      102        9099        855/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8098        548/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:34293         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       543071      1326/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          8930        792/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      107        9067        931/postgres
tcp6       0      0 ::1:7770                :::*                    LISTEN      1001       543920      1792/python
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          8101        548/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          541053      708/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          8932        792/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:703             0.0.0.0:*                           0          8097        548/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          8092        548/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::703                  :::*                                0          8100        548/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          8099        548/rpcbind
```

And I've trying to follow this solution : [Sending data to port does not seem to be working on Ubuntu Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509629/sending-data-to-port-does-not-seem-to-be-working-on-ubuntu-linux)

But it seems that not working. Is there a way to open the port 2003 please ? Or maybe someone who know graphite have a sugggestion to help me ? I can access to the graphite Web page but anything is display under graphite folder when I make a command test like this echo

`"test.count 4`date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003`

I can give more info if you want.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not open because nothing is listening on port 2003.
A port isn't a door for packets to come flying through, an application has to sit on it to accept them.

To me that suggests the thing you want to be listening there is either configured incorrectly or simply isn't running. I'm not familiar with either of the things you mentioned in the question (perhaps edit to link to them, or leave a comment), but nothing seems to be being "blocked".

Comment: Ok, that's true. In fact I found why that doesn't work : the command `service carbon-cache start` seems broken. Instead, I make like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301850/i-cant-see-my-data-in-graph-with-shinken-and-graphite/29345950#29345950 . Thanks Oli