# Forward terminal output to localhost port

Tags: command-line, localhost, sockets

I am new to tcp. Suppose I have a command to run on terminal that prints output line by line. How do I forward that output to a localhost port so that I can read it with other apps written in Python. From [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509629/sending-data-to-port-does-not-seem-to-be-working-on-ubuntu-linux), I set up a listening terminal with:

```
nc -l 2003
```

using port `2003`. Then I run my command like this :

```
mycommand | netcat localhost 2003
```

But nothing goes through.

If I test with

```
echo hello_world | netcat localhost 2003
```

I can receive the `hello_world` though. How do I create this transfer?

The command is a kafka-console-consumer.sh like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer --topic <topic_name> --from-beginning --bootstrap-server <dns:port> | netcat localhost 2003
```

Comment: Perhaps `your_command` output is being buffered? See for example [Make netcat a “stream”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302366/make-netcat-a-stream)

Comment: Thanks. You were right.